# Introduce time delay while detecting powered on state in an android app

Tags: android, timer, delay

Heyy!

I am creating a test app which detects whether the device is connected to any power source or not and correspondingly shows the status as "Charging" or "Discharging".It's working perfectly fine until here. 
Now what I want is that when I remove the power source, it should show "Discharging" after a delay of say 10 seconds. Within that 10 secs, if say, I reconnect the power source, the app won't bother updating its status and stay in the "Charging" state.
I would like to keep the delay time configurable.
How do I go about this? 
Here's the code snippet used till now. It displays the state of the device without any delay.

```
        BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context , Intent intent) {


        if(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.equals(intent.getAction())){


            int btstatus = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
            switch(btstatus)
            {
            case 1:
                status="Unknown";
                break;

            case 2:
                status="Charging";
                break;

            case 3:
                status="Discharging";
                break;

            case 4:
                status="Not charging";
                break;

            case 5:
                status="Battery Full";
                break;

                default: status= "Error!";

            }

                     tv2.setText(status);


//OnCreate method
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    tv1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

     registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));



}
//onDestroy()
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    unregisterReceiver(br);
      super.onDestroy();  


}
```

Comment: can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            // call a method that changes the state; don't change the state here, do it on the UI thread
        }
    }.execute();
```